# JQuery table filter is working too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a list filter, it works fine on small list but problem occurs on big list, it becomes very slow on that. if clicked on reset button or if some character is deleted the new list shows up so slow. there may be some problems with way of doing this please help me. following is my code:
HTML:

```
<div class="filter-wrap">
  <span class="clearable">
    <input class="data_field" name="data_field" id="brands-search" placeholder="Search Brands Here" type="text"/>
    <span class="icon_clear" style="cursor:pointer;">✘</span>
  </span>
  <div class="small-bt"><p class="common all">select all &nbsp|</p><p class="common none">&nbspunselect all</p></div>
  <div class="check-wrap" id="brands">
    <div class="check-unit">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
      <p class="slide-head brandList">Samsung</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.check-unit:nth-child(even)').css({'float':'right'});
function listFilter(list){
        $('.data_field').change( function () {
            var filter = $(this).val();
            if(filter) {
                $(list).children("p:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
                $(list).children("p:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
                //console.log($(".a:nth-child(1)").text());
              } else {
                $(list).children("p").parent().slideDown().removeClass("a");
              }
          })
        .keyup( function () {
            $(this).change();
        });
}
```

here `check-unit` is repeated. for full details please refer this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/BdRpk/

one more thing: to make a layout proper, I've used `$('.check-unit:nth-child(even)').css({'float':'right'});`(very first line of javascript). if you type something in inputbox the layout gets disturbed please tell me the solution of this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the performance is dropping for large volume of data because you are using the `slideUp()/slideDown()`. Why dont you use the `hide()` instead?

Below is a code which makes a filter/search functionality from a list of Contacts inside a div. The contacts were entered as child divs to another div

```
function searchContacts(entered_text){
    entered_text = entered_text.toUpperCase();//convert the filter value to uppercase to make it non case sensitive
    $("#external-events").children().show(); //Refresh the div containing the contact list. Id of the parent div is "external-events"
    var contactDivs = $("#external-events").children();
    for (var iter=0;iter<contactDivs.length ; iter++)
    {
        contactDivs[iter].firstChild.value = contactDivs[iter].firstChild.value.toUpperCase();
        if(contactDivs[iter].firstChild.value.indexOf(entered_text)== -1) {             // Does not contain
            $(contactDivs[iter]).hide();
        }
    }
}
```

This hides the other elements which does meet the criteria thus filtering out the ones which actually meet the criteria.

Comment: Did you try using the hide() function

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase performance of your code, don't use jQuery when you can do it in pure JS, before class selectors, try to apply the element, which will increase performance :

```
$('div.check-unit:even').css({'float':'right'});

// Why are you define evt handler in a function, and how many times do you call this function ? This could conduct to a huge memory use.

function listFilter(list){
    $('.data_field').keyup( function () {
        var filter = this.value;
        if(filter) {

            //Unoptimized code... Can you provide a fiddle to speed up the debug ?

            $(list).children("p:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
            $(list).children("p:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
            //console.log($(".a:nth-child(1)").text());
          } else {
            $(list).children("p").parent().slideDown().removeClass("a");
          }

           //END of Unoptimized code...
      });

}
```

Comment: I've already provided a fiddle check in the question.... sir I didn't get you exactly, please make it more clear.. what should I use instead of this `unoptimized code`